# Keep relative positioned images at the bottom when size of one changes

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have some images in a div, that grow bigger when i move my mose over them. My problem is, that if one of them gets bigger, the other images stay at the top of the div and move up.

I tried setting the bottom property of the images to 0, but that doesnt work because they are positioned relative. If I set their position to absolute and bring them to their right position, they overlap when they grow bigger.

I also tried to set the vertical-align of the parent div to bottom but that doesn't work either.

My HTML:

```
<div id="picmen">
    <img src="/images/b1.png" />
    <img src="/images/b2.png" />
    <img src="/images/b3.png" />
    <img src="/images/b4.png" />
    <img src="/images/b5.png" />
    <img src="/images/b6.png" />
    <img src="/images/b7.png" />
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
#picmen {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

#picmen img {
    float: right;
    margin: 3px 1px 3px 1px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

#picmen img:hover {
    transition-duration: 0.5s; 
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to play with #picmen height

```
#picmen {
position: absolute;
right: 0px;
bottom: 0px;
vertical-align: bottom;
height:63px}
```

On other hand all non-mouseover img should have a top value

```
#picmen img {
position:relative;
float: right;
margin: 3px 1px 3px 1px;
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
transition-duration: 0.5s;
top:6px}
```

There is an example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NAtJq/2/) , i just replaced the img by buttons, but it should be the same

Comment: Thank you, I changed the top:6px to top:10px and now it works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you use the scale effect instead of manually entering the image size on Hover
Something like this.

[WORKING FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/XZW9j/2/)

```
#picmen img:hover {
    transition-duration: 0.5s; 
    transform: scale(1.2);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.2); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2); /* Safari and Chrome */
}
```

You can also change the margins on hover to avoid overlap
    margin : 3px 4px 3px 4px;

[2nd FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/XZW9j/5/)

Comment: Because with scale the Images overlap and the scaled image grows over the bottom of the parent div.

Comment: That fixes the overlaping, but I want the bottom lines off all aligned